# Email's intermittently showing in inbox

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, iis

I have a Form App that is supposed to send a confirmation email whenever a user submits data. The issue is that the emails seems to show up intermittently. The good thing is that i can see that the data that the user submits populates within our ERP system 100% of the time (regardless if the confirmation email is sent or not).

I've also consistently seen these three errors get thrown, in the event viewer, whenever an email does not get sent.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGSsk.jpg)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqRvp.jpg)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVsXL.jpg)

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: The error shows that something wrong exists in code of middleware. It is better to use debug Diagnostic Tool to analysis code issue when application running on IIS. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210

Comment: @BruceZhang appreciate the tip!